# Task.WhenAll OperationContext null

Tags: c#, wcf

My code is akin to ...

```
var fetchers = [listOfDataFetchers]
var results = Task.WhenAll(fetchers.Select(x => x.Fetch()).Result
```

As a fetcher is basically waiting for a service to return data, this is a perfect use case for tasks and async.

However, the fetchers require `OperationContext.Current`, which I cannot inject directly in this case (yes, I am sure about that).

I've already tried to update to .net 4.6.2 as it supposedly fixed OperationContext.Current in async cases (and set `wcf:disableOperationContextAsyncFlow` to `false` in the web.config), but that didn't result in any change of the observed behavior.

So, short of going to something along the lines of

```
var oc = OperationContext.Current;
Parallel.ForEach(entries, entry =>
{
    OperationContext.Current = oc;
    Execute(entry);
});
```

do I have any options?

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimentation I figured out the issue. The fix was "simply" to not use `.Result` but `await` the `Thread.WhenAll`, letting async bubble up the stack to the service, so that the contract itself has an async signature.

My working assumption is that `.Result` "hides" the parallelism to WCF so the async context support added in .net 4.6.2 does not trigger. If anyone has more insights I would be more than happy to take corrections on that though.

Comment: Has the same problem. Found that only setting `wcf:disableOperationContextAsyncFlow` worked. Other sources (like this [one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/205803/wcf-operationcontextcurrent-problem-for-async-oper.html]) use the setting `Switch.System.ServiceModel.DisableOperationContextAsyncFlow` did not work for me.